# Elegant construct to trim/null values of the string parameters passed to the method

Tags: c#, .net, methods, syntax, parameters

Imagine we have following method:

```
void Write(int? id, string s1, string s2, ... , string s10)
{
    // prepare parameters:
    // null/trim all (or some of) the string parameters
    s1 = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s1) ? null : s1.Trim();
    s2 = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s2) ? null : s2.Trim();
    ...
    s10 = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s10) ? null : s10.Trim();

    // do write:
    WriteRaw(id, s1, s2, ... , s10);
}
```

Which writes a record to a database table. However, before data is written, there is the need to "normalize" parameters, e.g. trim/null those of them which are of the string type.

Is it possible to rewrite parameters preparation part in a more elegant manner? Something like:

```
void Write(int? id, string s1, string s2, ... , string s10)
{
    //pseudo code:
    { s1, s2, ... , s10 }.ForEach((ref s) => {
        s = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace ? null : s.Trim();
    });

    WriteRaw(id, s1, s2, ... , s10);
}
```

**UPD**: I'm not able to change signature of `WriteRaw`. Also besides parameters of the string type, there can be parameters of the other type, e.g.:

```
void SetContactInfo(int? id, string firstName, string middleName, string lastName, bool isActive, string xmlContacts)
{
   ...
   SetContactInfoRaw(id, firstName, middleName, lastName, isActive, xmlContacts);
}
```

Comment: methods with `params` can probably improve situation: `void Write(int? id, params string[] s)`, `void WriteRaw(int? id, params string[] s)` if you apply Trim logic to array elements: `s[i] = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s[i]) ? null : s[i].Trim()` in `for` loop

Comment: @ASh, unfortunately I can not change signature of `WriteRaw` method. Also in the real situation there can be parameters of another types. E.g. `SetContactInfo(int? id, string firstName, string middleName, string lastName, bool isActive, string xmlContacts)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can do it with something closely resembling your method,

```
var s = new [] {s1, s2, ... , s10}
    .Select( v => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v) ? null : v.Trim()).ToList();
WriteRaw(id, s[0], s[1], ... , s[9]);
```

a better approach would be to wrap the check into an extension method, and apply it in place:

```
WriteRaw(id, s1.NullTrim(), s2.NullTrim(), ... , s10.NullTrim());

// This goes to a separate static "helper" class
internal static string NullTrim(this string s) {
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? null : s.Trim();
}
```

The second approach is more economical, because it does not create new lists or arrays containing the strings to be "normalized".

Comment: First one looks less convenient for me, because of in this case there is the need to "map" formal parameter to array element and back. It is easy to do mistake in this place, so potentially it can be a source of semantic errors. Extension method keeps formal parameters names and seems acceptable. My initial thought was to write helper method `NullTrim(ref params string[] s) {...}`, and then use it before call to `WriteRaw` as `NullTrim(ref s1, ref s2, ... , ref s10)`, but, unfortunately, `ref params` is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Will this help?

```
void Write(int? id, params string[] values)
{
    var normalizedValues = values
        .Select(v => Normalize(v))
        .ToArray();

    // do the rest
}

string Normalize(string v)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v) ? null : v.Trim();
}
```

Note, that since `params` supports arrays only, it will be nice to have 
overload with `IEnumerable<string>` too:

```
void Write(int? id, IEnumerable<string> values)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to change method signature. Also, `params` is not suitable in my case, because of list of parameters can be a mixture of various types, e.g. `(int?, string, string, string, bool, int, bool, int, string)`, and each of the types may require "normalization". This way it will lead to form `Write(int? id, params string[] sa, params bool[] ba, params int[] ia)`, which is not possible. Though it may work in suitable situation.

Comment: @i-one: the workaround for the second restriction is `params object[]`. In fact, caller won't see the difference at source code level.

Answer (score -1):

Pass the s* parameters as an array or a maped object, then you will be able to manipulate the attributes better then now!